# Creating a dynamic list of tabs in Shiny from an Excel

Tags: r, list, shiny

I am trying to dinamically create a tabsetPanel by reading an Excel file.  Supossedly, when reading an excel, it has to read how many tabs does it have and create the different tabs including the content of the different sheets.

UI.R

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Generating an arbitrary number of tabs - assay 7bis"),
  sidebarPanel(   
    uiOutput("Radio"),
    radioButtons("fileType_Input", label = "Choose File type", choices = list(".csv/txt" = 1, ".xlsx" = 2), selected = 1, inline = TRUE),
    fileInput('datafile', 'Choose file',accept=c('application/vnd.ms-excel','text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain')),
    uiOutput("out1")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("twotabs")
    #div(style="display:inline-block; padding: 8px 12px",
    #    tabsetPanel(
    #      id = 'dataFiles',
    #      tabPanel("Lab1", htmlOutput("Lab1_html"), div(align = 'left', style = 'height: 600px; width:1300px; overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y: scroll', tableOutput('table1')), style = "width:100%"),
    #      tabPanel("Lab2", htmlOutput("Lab2_html"), div(align = 'left', style = 'height: 600px; width:1300px; overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y: scroll', tableOutput('table2')), style = "width:100%"),
    #      tabPanel("Lab3", htmlOutput("Lab3_html"), div(align = 'left', style = 'height: 600px; width:1300px; overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y: scroll', tableOutput('table3')), style = "width:100%")
    #    )
    #)
  )
))
```

SERVER.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  ## List of datasets to read: for an excel we can have more than one sheet.
  observeEvent(input$fileType_Input,{
    listData <- list(NULL)
  })
  ## Reading the file.
  listData <- reactive({
    auxList <- list(NULL)
    infile <- input$datafile
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      # User has not uploaded a file yet
      return(auxList)
    }
    # 
    # Depending on the radioButton value, the file should be CSV or XLSX.
    if ((infile$type == 'text/csv' || infile$type == 'application/vnd.ms-excel') & input$fileType_Input == "1") {
      # CSV File.
      auxList[[1]] <- read.csv(infile$datapath)
      listSheetsNames <- list("CSV")
      nSheets <- 1
      #
    } else if (infile$type == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' & input$fileType_Input == "2") {
      # XLSX file.
      wbFile <- loadWorkbook(infile$datapath)
      sheetsFile <- getSheets(wbFile)
      listSheetsNames <- names(sheetsFile)
      #
      # Reading any of the sheets.
      for (j in 1:length(sheetsFile)){
        auxList[[j]] <- read.xlsx(infile$datapath, sheetIndex = j, sheetName = NULL, as.data.frame = TRUE, header = TRUE)
      }
      nSheets <- length(sheetsFile)
    } else {
      nSheets <- 0
      listSheetsNames <- NULL
      auxList <- NULL
    }
    #
    list(nSheets = nSheets, strNames = listSheetsNames, lData = auxList)
  })
  ##
  ## Tabs.
  output$twotabs <- renderUI({
    listAuxData <- listData()
    if (!is.null(listAuxData$lData)) {
      listTabs <- list(NULL)
      for (i in 1:listAuxData$nSheets) {
        listTabs[[i]] <- tabPanel(listAuxData$strNames[i],
                                  tableOutput(paste0("table",i))
        )
        ##
      }
      listTabs$id <- "dataFiles"
      do.call(tabsetPanel, listTabs)
    }
  })
  ##
  ## Tables
  observe({
    listAuxData <- listData()
    if (!is.null(listAuxData$lData)) {
      for (k in 1:listAuxData$nSheets) {
        # Fill the tabs.
        nameTable <- paste0("table",k)
        dd <- listAuxData$lData[[k]]
        output[[nameTable]] <- renderTable({dd}, striped=TRUE, bordered = TRUE, align = "l", digits = 0)
      }
      updateTabsetPanel(session, "dataFiles")
    }
  })
  ##
})
```

I was expecting the content on any sheet, in the different tabs created dinamically.  What do I obtain?  I obtain always the last sheet on the excel file on any of the tabs created (which were well created).

When I do it statically, using a static tabsetPanel, it works.  When pretending I know how many sheets do i have in the excel, for example 3, I put one single number ...

```
dd <- listAuxData$lData[[1]]
```

... instead of the counter variable, it works and it shows me exactly the sheet I put.  But, when using the dynamic counter, always put in the three tabs the content of the last sheet.

I was fighting during days with this and I didn't find the solution yet.

Thanks in advance.